# Як перекласти "just-in-time"

Tags: from-english, вибір-слова

Стаття на вікіпедії називається [Якраз вчасно](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7_%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE), а мені якось більше звучало б *саме вчасно*. Який варіант правильніший?

Comment: Я б сказала *(в) акурат вчасно*. СУМ: [*акурат*](http://sum.in.ua/s/akurat), Wiki: [*акурат*](http://wiki.kubg.edu.ua/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82). Утім, не бачу проблем ні з *саме*, ні з *якраз*.

Comment: Не знаю, який у Вас контекст. Он та ж Вікпедія пропонує варіант «[на льоту](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIT-компіляція)».

Comment: [E2U](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=just+in+time&dicts=all&highlight=on): «са́ме вча́сно», «в саму́ пору́», «са́ме в час»; [Англо-український тлумачний словник **економічної** лексики 2004 (Анна Шимків)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=just-in-time&dicts=12&highlight=on): «точно в строк» («~ system» → «система „точно в строк“», «~ production» → «система виробництва „точно в строк“»).

Answer (score 1):

Можливий варіант як і "саме вчасно", так і "якраз вчасно". Слово "just" може  перекладатися як "саме" чи "якраз", а от "in time" перекладається лише як "вчасно" (див. Гугл Перекладач та цей [сайт](https://entelechy.com.ua/on-time-in-time/)). До речі, навіть на зазначеному мною сайті зможете знайти приклад: "You are just in time for dinner!" - "Ти якраз вчасно на обід!".